# Distributing a glassfish server application

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

So ive made a client-server application with java and Netbeans , the server is a glassfish server and they communicate with SOAP .

Everything is working perfectly , but the problem is that its a uni project and they dont look at the source code , they need binaries or jars .

Now when you build a web app , the IDE generates a .war file that would be deployed in your glassfish server (thats how i know it works , correct me if im wrong) .So in order for it to work on another PC that PC would need to have glassfish installed ?

Usually the teacher would click some "client.exe" and a "server.exe" and test things out , but im afraid this wouldnt work this time .

Is there a way like an .exe that opens a window and one would select what .war to deploy or the teacher has to install glassfish and go to admin page and deploy the war just like i would do on my PC ? if its the only way i can include a glassfish installation with some tutorial in a power point to explain how to deploy the app ... but i wonder if theres a fool-proof way since i dont know if my teacher is smart enough to do it the right way .

Comment: Glassfish comes with grizzly bundled in.  You can always just create a class with a `main()` which launches an embedded grizzly server with your server deployed in it, instead of creating a war which needs to be deployed instead an external web server.

Answer (score 0):

Actually he would need to deploy the application on a local application server as well. Unfortunately the only solution I can think of is to make it accessible via public URL. Maybe your university does provide some kind of a free VPS.

Answer (score 0):

If (!) Java SDK 7 is installed you could try [Payara](http://www.payara.fish/) [Micro](http://www.payara.fish/payara_micro), which is derived from GlassFish 4 and enables you to run war files from the command line without any application server installation.